# camel: setting body and forwarding inside nested loop

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route that uses groovy inside transform tag to set message body to a list. The problem is the message body is set inside of nested loops. Once the  message body is set, I need to send message to a separate route, and do this in a loop. I don't have a clear idea about how I can do this inside iterations. This is what I have right now:

```
    <route id="contentSearch">
        <from uri="direct:contentSearch" />            
        <transform>
            <groovy>
                def endPoint = camelContext.getEndpoint("activemq:contentPageHandler");
                def producer = endPoint.createProducer();
                for(cur in body['type'])
                {
                    ......
                     for(sec in body['section'])
                     {    
                        ........                  
                        def exchange = endPoint.createExchange();
                        exchange.getIn().setBody(contentList);
                        producer.process(exchange);

                     }
                  }

            </groovy>
        </transform>            
    </route>
```

With what I have above, I'm getting error:

```
    The target server failed to respond
    org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
```

The rout that I'm trying to reach is this:

```
    <route id="contentPageHandler">
        <from uri="activemq:contentPageHandler?transacted=true"/>          
        <log message="!!! body:${body}" logName="logContentPageHandler"/>    
    </route>
```

I have to admit, I'm not sure what is going wrong here since I'm pretty new to camel. I would like to be able to use the log named "logContentPageHandler"  inside the groovy code I have above, but so far I had no success with it either. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are really trying to do, but I will try to explain from a high level.

There are different constructs in camel that are used to different things. The intent of the transformer is to transform and return the payload. Then you can use a [splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter) to send various parts of the message to an endpoint. Don't use the groovy transformer for everything.

My take would be to use that groovy code to create a `java.util.List` of "sections".

```
<transform>
 <groovy>
   for(sec in body['section']){
      // create a list..
   }
   return listOfSections;
  </groovy>
</transform>
<split>
 <simple>${body}</simple>
 <to uri="activemq:contentPageHandler"/>
</split>
```

To use the log inside the groovy code, you will have to create a [org.slf4j.Logger](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html)  object with the expected name and use it.

**Edit:**

To really send multiple messages from a groovy transformer, use the `ProducerTemplate` to fire off multiple messages. It has various methods to send (depends on Message Exchange Pattern, check out the docs). Untested code, but should work. Please note, you should probably not create the ProducerTemplate too many times. It's better to reuse a single template, but this will illustrate the concept.

```
<transform>
        <groovy>
            def producer = camelContext.createProducer();

            for(cur in body['type'])
            {
                ......
                 for(sec in body['section'])
                 {    
                    ........                  
                    producer.sendBody("activemq:contentPageHandler",contentList);

                 }
              }

        </groovy>
    </transform>
```

Comment: Hi Petter, thank you for the post. The problem I'm having is that the array is one page out of many pages. This is why there cant be a single return statement for a single array - the loops have to keep bringing more pages/arrays - this is a "bulk" processing.

Comment: Ok, hard to tell exactly. I still guess you could do something with the splitter. Anyhow, you should go with the `ProducerTemplate`in your code. Check this example out: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-write-a-custom-processor-which-sends-multiple-messages.html

Comment: Updated answer about sending from transformers

Comment: The producer classes are not really intended to be used directly like that, so - not sure. The ProducerTemplate is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The error was a timeout error related to synchronization. I had to change my "to" tag to "inOnly" tag, and also had to change the "from" direct:

```
<from uri="direct:contentSearch" />
```

to "from" activemq

```
<from uri="activemq:contentSearch?transacted=true" />
```